# populus : how do i deploy a contract with args in the constructor?

Tags: dapp-development, contract-deployment, framework, populus

Suppose I have a contract with some parameters that can be passed in the constructor, how am I suppose to pass them within the framework ?

I tried to search the docs at the [deploy](http://populus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/populus.overview.html#deploy) part but can't find the answer there.

I see that [git pull](https://github.com/pipermerriam/populus/pull/17) that seems to be kind of what I want, but I fail at knowing how practically I can pass them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current best way to do this is to include a contract with the parameters hard coded like the following.

```
contract HasParameters {
    function A(uint value) {
    }
}

contract HardCodedParameters is HasParameters(12345) {
    function HardCodedParameters() {}
}
```

This will allow you to run `populus deploy HardCodedParameters` and have the contract deployed with the provided constructor parameters.

> I Understand this workaround isn't ideal and won't work for all situations.  It is not entirely clear to me the best way to implement this in a generic way so that it can be done entirely from the command line.  I'm very open to discussion on [this github issue](https://github.com/ethereum/populus/issues/82) if you have opinions on how this should work.

Comment: waiting for the json ;)